# How can I ensure a generic payload in a .Net API Dto?

Tags: c#, .net, api, dto, composition

I have a DTO for creating a client organisation.

```
public record clientDto(string legalname, string name, string country, australianClientData payload);

public record australianClientData(int abn);
```

These attributes in `australianClientData` are specific to Australian organisations. Organisations from other countries will have their own specific attributes.

How do I ensure that `payload` is of a type that allows different child types (ie. usaClientData, chinaClientData)?

### Failed attempt #1 - Use a base class

I have already tried making `australianClientData` inherit from a base class `parentPayload`. The problem with this is that my Controller assumed the payload was of base class (empty) so it ignored it entirely.

### Failed attempt #2 - Use a generic class

@stuartd Here is what I've come up with.

```
    public record clientDto(string legalname, string name, string country);
    public record clientDto<TCountry>(string legalname, string name, string country, TCountry? payload) where TCountry : parentPayload;

    public abstract record parentPayload();
    public record payloadAustraliaClientData(int abn, string aciclabel, string acicofficecode) : parentPayload;
```

```
[HttpPost]
        public clientDto Post([FromBody] clientDto clientObject)
        {
            return clientObject;
        }
```

Problem is that I'm having difficulty returning the correct type from my API. I understand that `clientDto<TCountry>` is different from `clientDto` (and my data can be either), but my API accepts and returns `clientDto`. I am inexperienced enough in C# that I don't know how to expect or return the appropriate type.

Comment: Don't think this works with records (yet?) but `clientDto<TCountry>(string legalname, string name, string country, TCountry payload)` comes to mind, perhaps also with `where TCountry : parentPayload`

Comment: can you show usaClientData too , Pls

Comment: @stuartd I've given your idea a go, and I'm still running into an issue where it returns a the clientDto with no payload attached.

Comment: @Serge, sorry it has not been implemented. At this stage only `payloadAustraliaClientData` will be implemented.

Comment: Then it is too early to post the question here , since you don't know what you need

Comment: @Serge I would still like to know wheter this is a good way of expanding DTOs.

Comment: @LukeMartin It is just a waste of time. Maybe you don't need to expand at all, or maybe you  will have to create the separate action for each payload or use JToken for example

Comment: Okay thanks @Serge. I'll go with beautifulcoder's answer; it seems simple. By the time I have to implement something more complex, I'll hopefully know more about .Net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is to use optional properties:

```cs
public record clientData(int? abn, int? ssn);
```

Then have the API *implicitly* figure out the underlying DTO. You could also strongly type the request via an enum:

```cs
public record clientData(ClientType type, int? abn, int? ssn);
```

This way the API knows which properties to pluck and fail the request when they are missing.

Comment: I might just do this to begin with, as it's straightforward, and adding additional countries is a later problem (parent company only serves Australia atm). Thank you.

Comment: I've seen plenty of systems store TFN or SSN in the same "Tax Number" field.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman That's not a bad idea, but ABN (business number) seems analogous to the USA EIN, and TFN -> SSN.